# Ionic and Android 6.0 Marshmallow

Tags: ionic-framework

Is there anyone who has tested an ionic application in 6.0 Marshmallow android? I want to know if it works without problems?

Comment: Your question as it stands doesn't make much sense to me as there are literally millions of users out there using Ionic-Framework with Android 6.0 devices, so you should probably be more specific, and also consider adding an Android tag and Cordova tag. My best guess is that I think you're trying to ask if there are issues with apps that were tested/published on earlier versions of Android that predate 6.0, which are now problematic, so I've tried to address that in my answer.

Comment: The initial release of Android 6.0 was October 5, 2015. I guess it works by now and you can safely develop Ionic apps on it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm testing every app I make on 6.0.1 and everything works fine. Weird question you asked there...

Answer (score 0):

We have apps that run on both earlier versions of Android, and Android 6.0. Some changes were required relating to the new permissions system introduced in Android 6.0. So, if you're using certain device features, you'll need to adjust appropriate entries in your config.xml. Here's a snippet from one of our apps, to give you an idea, which we use in conjunction with the `cordova-plugin-settings-hook` plugin:

```
<platform name="android">
    <config-file parent="/*" platform="android" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
        <uses-feature    android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    </config-file>
```

You'll also need to change the widget element to include an xmlsn:android setting for the above settings to work:

`<widget xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ... >`

You can learn more about that here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-settings-hook

Comment: I'm not using any of this things nor setting permissions in config.xml, and everything works fine. What does this exactly do and what is the bad thing about not using it?

Comment: If you're using certain device features in your app, such as the camera, microphone, or GPS functionality, you now need to use settings like these on Android 6.0+ and iOS 10.0+. (For iOS the settings are different.)

Comment: If you're not using any mobile device features then you don't need them.

Comment: What I was saying is that I am making apps for devices and using them on devices using various plugins that require permissions. What happens in Android 6.0 + is that device asks for your permission once you start using the plugin, i.e. in a runtime, and you accept it and everything works fine. You can even request permissions on install using diagnostics plugin, but I never ran into doing what you posted above. Maybe I miss understood you, maybe you use this when moving your apps from < 6.0 to 6.0+ Android?

Comment: By the way I'm on Ionic 1.x, maybe this is the thing you do on Ionic 2+ since I didn't have much work with 2. I did some but it could be that I missed that